# How to check if a string contains alternate characters in swift?

Tags: swift, string, character

Like if we have a String **"ababab"** or **"ababa"**, the String is valid but if it is like **"aabab"** or **"abbaab"**, then it is invalid.

Comment: What's not working in your version, where do you struggle, specifically? Please include your attempt in the question.

Comment: What about "aaaaaa"?

Comment: So we can say that __A String is valid if and only if the 3rd character is `a`__ :D As  you can see, examples are good but there are many different rules compatible with your example set. Please don't ask us to guess the rule, just tell us ;-)

Comment: The rule for input is, the input string will only contain two different alphabets, any number of time. I need to check whether the string is in the format where an alphabet's left and right neighbours are different from the current alphabet, holding true for all characters in the string. Then it is a valid case else its an invalid case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### IF...

...the rule is the following

> A String is valid if 2 consecutives characters are always different

then here's the code

```
let txt = "ababab"

let valid = !zip(txt.characters, txt.characters.dropFirst()).contains { $0 == $1 }
```